# Adding a new column at the start of an excel table in an excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am wondering how one can insert a new column at the beginning of an excel spreadsheet using C sharp.net.  I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;  I want to use OLEO to do this, but I don't see that happening.  I have been searching google on how to do this for the last two days now.  I can't understand why there are not more tutorials on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout out the [Range.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.insert%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method which you can call on a range of cells to insert entire rows/columns in front of them:

```
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet) workBookIn.Sheets[1]; // Worksheet indexes are one based

Range rng = sheet.get_Range("A1", Missing.Value);

rng.EntireColumn.Insert(XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,
                        XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
```

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but I think the code section that you have there doesn't necessarily square with what you are saying...

Comment: Hey Michael.  What is Missing.Value by the way?  Should that be Type.Missing?

Comment: Also, how do I save this new worksheet to see if have made any discernable changes?