# Insert Columns between columns in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have an Excel File in which I have number of columns. Now I need to insert columns for example between "C" and "D".. so that the resulting columns should be "C" ,"New Column(D)", "E".. Please help me with this..

Parts of Code to open the Excel file is as below...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(txtDestination.Text.ToString() + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(File_Name, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

Comment: CHECK THIS :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532775/adding-a-new-column-at-the-start-of-an-excel-table-in-an-excel

Answer (score 11):

I do it like this:

Select the column you want to insert the new column next to

```
Excel.Range oRng = oSheet.Range["I1"];
```

Insert the new column, specifying the direction you want to shift existing columns.
In this case, we insert a new column to the left of I1; I1 will become H1

```
oRng.EntireColumn.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight, 
                    Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromRightOrBelow);
```

To do something with the new column, such as set the header value, select the I1 range again.

```
oRng = oSheet.Range["I1"];
```

Set the column header text

```
oRng.Value2 = "Discount";
```

Comment: Be aware that the number of columns inserted is proportional to the number of columns in the active selection.

Answer (score 0):

reposting the above comment as an answer so question may be marked as answered.

Please see: [Adding a new column at the start of an excel table in an excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7532775/adding-a-new-column-at-the-start-of-an-excel-table-in-an-excel) for solution. All you need do is change the "A1" value to the column you wish to insert before ("D1" in your example)

Answer (score 0):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(txtDestination.Text.ToString() + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(File_Name, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet;
```