# Insert Column in Excel doesn't work in C#

Tags: c#, excel

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;


Excel.Range r = sheet.get_Range(ExcelAssistant.c1ToA(Column_Date + i) + Row_Date_Insert, ExcelAssistant.c1ToA(Column_Date + i) + (Row_Date_Insert + sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count));

Console.WriteLine("range r property" + r.Address);

r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight,Missing.Value);
r.Insert();
sheet.Columns[Column_Date + i].insert();
```

ExcelAssistant is an Excel Util  class and it has static method c1ToA to transfer the interger of the column number into the "ABC" Format.

I use the Console.WriteLine to ensure I point to correct position.

Then I tried several insert method above but none works.

What' wrong?

Any help may be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try like this -> `r.EntireColumn.Insert()`

Comment: Yeah,I tried  it,but it didn't work neither.

Comment: what do you get in the Console from printing `r.Address`?

Comment: And you may try to see `Console.WriteLine(r.Parent.Name)` to see whether you are refering the correct worksheet.

Comment: r.Address is right,like $C$2:$C$10

Comment: the sheet is OK too,I couldn't find the bug.

Comment: Can you make it like `C2` only? And take a llok at the parameters of ` `Insert()`

Comment: I'm not familiar with C#,I may not to make it like this format"C2".But since it is right and it's not null,I think this is not a big problem.Or could you tell me the difference between them?

Comment: I mean, can you make it just `$C$2`, refering just to one cell, not to a range?

Comment: Insert()has two parameters,one controls the direction and the other decides the format.I read the msdn and find no help.

Comment: Yeah,I can ,Let me try.================Nothing works.Thank you.

Comment: Take a look here as well -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605432/insert-columns-between-columns-in-excel

Comment: I have seen it before and it doesn't work.

Comment: Well,I got it.I didn't have other sheets into insert column loop.How can I close it，thanks.

Comment: What do you want to close?

Comment: Close this question,I don't want this topic  wasting time.

Comment: Just accept the answer below with the green check next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you insert a column:

```
r.EntireColumn.Insert()
```

Take a look here as well:
[Insert Columns between columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605432/insert-columns-between-columns-in-excel)

Comment: Well,I forgot to insert column in other sheets in a loop  .So I always  get the wrong result.Thank you,again.

Comment: I only have the first sheet inserted the column,but I have never checked it until now.