# How to copy one column properties to newly created column

Tags: c#-4.0

After adding new column, we want to assign some particular column property to newly added column.

Measure Behavior:  It's taking last column properties while adding new one.

How we can add new column with needed properties?

We are trying to add new column with below code in C#.

```
line = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Columns[ColumnNumber];
line.Insert();
```

Comment: i think this might help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605432/insert-columns-between-columns-in-excel)

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

But with mention code also we can add new column in between two present column. But that is also taking previous column properties(Format).

For Example : We have Column B,C and D.
If I will add column in between C and D then it's become B,C,D and E.

But automatically D(new Added column) will take formats as C where I want new added column formats should be as B.

Comment: try this private string[] map = new string[]
    { 
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" .............
    };

public string getColumn(int number)
{
    return map[number];
}

with this you can get the column if you want exactly fitting the column you need to define how many column you have and keep some for you to swift?